# split class definitions in Xamarin

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, definition

I am developing a cross platform app in xamarin.  I want to define multiple classes in my shared library but then implement them using platform specific code for each platform.  These classes will be referenced in my main view model to control different features (eg. battery level, wifi, usb camera). What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamarin you can accomplish this making use of interfaces. In C# using interfaces you define a contract that must be met by any class that implement it.

Using your example, let's say you have in your shared folder an interface called `IBatteryService`.

```
public interface IBatteryService
{
     double GetBatteryLevel();
}
```

You will have three implementations of this interface in each of the platform project: iOS, Android and UWP. These implementations will have the platform specific code to get what you are looking.

```
public class BatteryServiceIOS : IBatteryService
{
    public double GetBatteryLevel()
    {
        ///
        /// iOS code to get the device battery level
        ///

        return batteryLevel;
    }
}
```

Your ViewModels will use the interface making the code agnostic of which implementation is being used.

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    IBatteryService _batteryLevel;

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        //You will initialize your instance either using DI (Dependency Injection or by using ServiceLocator.
    }

    public double GetDeviceBatteryLevel()
    {
         // At this moment the VM doesn't know which implementation is used and it actually doesn't care.
         return _batteryLevel.GetBatteryLevel();
    }
}
```

In your app composition root, with the help of an iOC will define which implementation is gonna be used. Every platform will be registering it's own implementation. Then in your ViewModels you will inject or get by using ServiceLocator the implementation that was registered.

In general this is the way Xamarin plugins work. You can take a look at the [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin) plugin code in github.

Here's a good tutorial which explain more about [C# IoC](http://joelabrahamsson.com/inversion-of-control-an-introduction-with-examples-in-net/)

Hope this is clear enough.